# DELETE a table in Riak TS

Tags: riak, riak-ts

I am attempting to drop an entire table in RIAK TS, but nothing seems to work. I have tried both "drop table" in a standard query so (using Python):

```
from riak import RiakClient
client = RiakClient(host = '127.0.0.1')
client.ts_query('ticks', 'DROP TABLE ticks')
```

but this gives me an error that DROP is not understood. An alternative would be to delete everything in the table using client.ts_delete('ticks', ["rows"]) but this seems to need me to specify the row keys. Is there a wildcard option for row keys, and if not, how do I get *all* row keys given the subquery size limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Riak TS 1.4.0 DROP TABLE is not supported and there is no other means to delete tables.

Range deletes (or deleting more than one row) is also not yet supported however you can batch delete statements.

ALTER, DROP, and range deletes are all features on the Riak TS road map for future releases.