# Alter table in Riak TS and new column

Tags: alter-table, riak-ts

I have Table having lots of data in Riak time series, but now I want to make this **table alter** to add some columns, How can I do that?

I tried:

```
 alter table Person add column designation varchar(23);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Extension alter not implemented.

Suggest me soon!

Comment: achually i tries this:--alter table Person add column designation varchar(23); ........forget to mention datatype

Comment: Do you get any Error messages or what exactly is your question?

Comment: Also you have a typo it's "alter" not "aletr"

Comment: Yes,  I tried with :-  alter table Person add column designation varchar(23);  But getting Extension alter not implemented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DELETE a table in Riak TS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698599/delete-a-table-in-riak-ts)

Answer (score 0):

ALTER and DROP are not currently supported in Riak TS (Version 1.4) See the following question for more details: [DELETE a table in Riak TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698599/delete-a-table-in-riak-ts)